# How to determine if a file is NOT-executable in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am looping through a directory and need to find all files that are not executable. I know

```
if [ -x $dir ]; then 
    echo "$dir is an executable file"
fi
```

shows that it is executable but how do I do the opposite of this? I have tried

```
if [ !-x $dir ]; then 
    echo "$dir is not-executable"
fi
```

however that does not work.

Comment: Spacing is crucial in shell scripts.  There's a vast difference between `[ !-x $dir ]` and `[ ! -x $dir ]` (and you should use `[ ! -x "$dir" ]` to avoid some surprises).

Answer (score 4):

Running the line through [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) shows:

```
if [ !-x $dir ]; then
      ^-- SC1035: You are missing a required space here.
         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Adding the missing space and quotes results in:

```
if [ ! -x "$dir" ]; then
```

You can also put the `!` outside the brackets using the generic syntax `if ! command`, which works on any command:

```
if ! [ -x "$dir" ]; then
```

Answer (score 4):

Either:

```
if ! [ -x "$dir" ]; then 
    echo "$dir is not an executable file"
fi
```

or:

```
if [ ! -x "$dir" ]; then 
    echo "$dir is not an executable file"
fi
```

will work.  In general, any command can be negated by `!`.  So if `cmd` returns non-zero, `! cmd` returns zero.  The `[` command also accepts `!` as an argument, so that `[ expression ]` is inverted with `[ ! expression ]`.  Which you choose is pretty much a stylistic choice and makes little difference.

Of course, you can also just do:

```
if [ -x "$dir" ]; then
    :
else
    echo "$dir is not an executable file"
fi
```